# Multiple libraries with one header c++

Tags: c++, header, linker, cmake

I am working on a project where I have the fallowing scenario. 
I have:

1. a header, call it header.h
2. a script which for a given set of parameters generates a .cpp which implements the header. Let's call the first one foo.cpp.

I have built a small interface to header.h, call it header_interface.h, since header.h is developed and maintained from an outside source. 
Now I want to use foo.cpp and header.h as a library, so in my CMakeLists.txt I add a foo library and in my program I include header_interface.h and then link the program to the foo library.

Now, if I have another auto-generated file, bar.cpp, and I want to use bar library, I don't have to change anything in my program, just link to bar instead of foo.

But, it might happen that I need both foo and bar in my program, for example if the libraries give me two different solutions to a problem and I need both solutions. Obviously I cannot do as before, since the #include "header_interface.h" would be ambiguous, and also creating a member of HeaderInterface class would cause problems.

What would be the best solution for solving this problem. Is there a way of solving this without having to create multiple copies of header_interface.h, which I would call for example header_interface_foo.h and change the name of HeaderInterface class inside?

Thank you!

Comment: In other words, you have *two different libraries* which use *header files with same names* (but with different locations), haven't you? If so, it is bad design: different libraries should use different headers. BTW, showing code examples(even short) will describe your situation more clearly than it is currently described without code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I have two libraries which use the same header, because they just implement the same header in different ways. I will try to provide some snippets, but it seems to me that is clear since both foo and bar will the same methods implemented, just differently.

Comment: Hm, if `foo` and `bar` implement *same library* (but in different ways), how these two implementation can be usefull in the same program? I cannot imagine that fact.

Comment: Say the library computes a distance in space. Now header.h has a class with one method, say double ComputeDistance(double point1, double point2). foo and bar are autogenerated by an external program, and they compute distances in different ways, one computes L1 distance, and the other L2 distance for example (in 1D it's the same, but for the sake of argument asume it is not). Then they would both implement the same header, but in different ways. My program could require both ways of calculating the distance, so I would need to link to both libraries.

Comment: So you need three headers. One with the abstract class describing your inteface. And a header for every realisation, which contains a class that derives from (or fulfills) the first class.